# Flutter Firestore getDocuments() not working on initState

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I'm having an issue trying to call a document from Firestore in initState. I can pull data from a StreamBuilder just fine, but I just want to call the data once on initState.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
class _PainLevelState extends State<PainLevel> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final CollectionReference userCollection =
      Firestore.instance.collection('users');
  static final now = DateTime.now();
  String _uid;
  double myPainLevel = 0;

  Future<void> getCurrentUser() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _uid = user.uid;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> getCurrentPainLevel() async {
    await userCollection
        .document(_uid)
        .collection('pain')
        .where('time',
            isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day))
        .getDocuments()
        .then((QuerySnapshot docs) {
      if (docs.documents.isNotEmpty) {
        print('yes');
      } else {
        print('no'); 
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
    getCurrentPainLevel();
  }

...
```

I just get a "no" every time I print to console. It's not get any documents when there is one. If I take the same code inside the future and put it somewhere else, like in the build method, it works, but it constantly builds and I don't want that. Any suggestion as to why it is not working? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing here that your code will not always work, because `getCurrentPainLevel` might get called before `getCurrentUser` is completed, which will cause `_uid` to be null and therefore, not work as expected. Try to put `then` keyword after `getCurrentUser` method, like this:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser().then((_) {
      getCurrentPainLevel();
    });
  }
```

By the way, you should NOT be calling async methods in initState. Try to put the code somewhere else, like `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(...)`.

Comment: That makes sense now. Thank you! I changed the initState to `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => getCurrentPainLevel());` and just added `final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();` to the `getCurrentPainLevel()` method, and changed `_uid` to `user.uid`. It works now. :)